How to monitor via serial monitor ESP32-H2 board while it is powered by external power source?
I'd like to monitor (via serial monitor) my ESP32-H2 while is powered from an external power source at 3.3 V or 5 V.

I think that I must use an USB connection to the board but for this purpose (serial monitor) but, at the same time, I've read on the ESP32-H2-DevKitM-1 official guide that, textually:

Power Supply Options There are three mutually exclusive ways to
provide power to the board:


a) USB Type-C to UART port, default power supply
b) 5V and GND pin headers
c) 3V3 and GND pin headers

At this point it seems to me that the only available port for serial monitor is the ESP32-H2 USB Type-C Port.

But if I use this ESP32-H2 USB Type-C Port for serial monitor connected via USB to the PC, there may be the risk that I've simultaneously two power source for the board?
Any idea?
Thanks in advance
